# VB6/W7 cannot kill a file on a network drive

Tags: windows-7, vb6

Sometimes you do not choose. I am dealing with an old VB code. It used to be VB4/W3.11. It has been ported to VB6/W7. I am performing a Kill from a VB6 appication on a file on a network drive (the distant machine is also W7). I get "Permission denied" error message eventhough the permissions are at their lower level (Everyone can do everything).

I then cannot delete the file using Windows Explorer. Neither from the machine where the VB6 app is running nor from the machine which is hosting the network drive. I have error messages similar to "This action cannot be completed because the file is open in System". I also tried del /f. I also tried to repeat the operations from an Admin account. Unsuccesful too.

I have tried Unlocker. The utility does not see any handle on the file. It cannot delete the file either.

Would anyone have an idea on how to diagnose and/or resolve the issue, or at least delete the file?

Thanks

Vincent

Comment: Try booting in safe mode and see if the file can be deleted manually.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Unfortunaly the file is located on a machine which should be operating 24h a day. I would rather find a solution without rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't delete the file manually, that kind of shows you the problem is not with the code.

Lets experiment, first try to rule out that the file is locked, create a temp file on the network drive and try to `Kill` it manually and through the program.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. My intuition is that the Kill in VB6 is leaving the file in a strange state. I have already tried to create a temp file on the network drive and delete it. I had no problem. I will create a small VB app with a simple Kill and test it next time I will go to this machine.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a look around and found the following links that *may* be useful to you...

http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/resource-monitor-find-process-locked-file-windows-7/
http://windowsxp.mvps.org/processlock.htm

This third one is specific to VB6...

http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_is_file_locked.html

Comment: Thanks for those inputs. Meanwhile the problem has disappeared. Those issues are the best one ;-)

Comment: Haha!  That happens to me frequently!  Good luck.